# Get Mathematica to factor constants out of definite integral

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Say we have

```
Integrate[a f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

And want Mathmatica to factor out `a` to get

```
a Integrate[f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

This works automatically for the indefinite integral

```
Integrate[a f[x],x]
```

but I need it to work for the definite one in order to further simplify long expressions. Just applying `Factor` doesn't do it and `FullSimplify` even with assumption `Element[a,Reals]` doesn't either.

Am I missing some obvious assumption that makes it work? Or do I have to write some pattern matching expression?

Quite possibly related is the fact that Mathematica doesn't see an equality here:

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[a f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 
  a Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], Element[a, Reals]]
```

This just returns the input expression again:

```
Integrate[a f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 
 a Integrate[f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Edit: I just checked and this is even true if we make replace `a` by a natural number directly! Again the unaltered expression is returned.

I am on Mathematica 10.1.0.0

Comment: `Integrate[a f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. 
  Integrate[a_, b_] :> Integrate[a, x] /. 
 Integrate[a_, b_] :> Integrate[a, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`?

Comment: @kglr This works if `x` is the actual integration variable while `a` can be replaced by another symbol in this expression. I guess I was expecting something that would do it at once for integrals over any variable but for my current purpose this is actually enough.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Yes! Thanks! This is close enough for a duplicate for me. The provided solution does what I want and is more general than klgr's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    factorConstant[integral_] := 
 ToExpression[
  StringReplace[ToString[integral], 
   "Integrate[" ~~ x_ -> x ~~ "*Integrate["]]
```

Then

```
factorConstant[Integrate[a f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
(*a Integrate[f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]*)
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a long expression with many integrals (and some non-integral terms) in it. So threading this into the right places is unfeasible.